# dotenv.config() fails to load variables into a Node project without raising an error

Tags: node.js, dotenv

Windows 10.

I am trying to load env variables into my Node.JS server API. I `require("dotenv").config()` as the first line of my `server.js` file. It does not throw an error when I check if the object is an error, as advised by the docs. If I use `{debug: true}`, it does not complain into console either. My `.env` file is in the root directory of the project, and if I move it, debug complains, so I presume config() successfully finds it.

When inspected through `console.log(process.env.PORT)`, the variable PORT the code was supposed to set is `undefined`. If I expect the object process.env itself, it has all the system variables but not the ones I want to load.

Problem reproduces with the following setup:

```
project
|- dotenvTest.js
|- .env
```

dotenvTest.js:

```
require('dotenv').config({debug: true});
console.log(process.env.PORT);
```

.env:

```
PORT=5000
```

Running node dotenvTest.js:

```
> node dotenvTest.js

undefined
```

When I do:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
console.log(dotenv.config().parsed);
```

it prints `{}`. However,

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const buf = Buffer.from('PORT=5000')
const config = dotenv.parse(buf)
console.log(config)
```

gives me `{ PORT: '5000' }`.

Things I have tried:

- renaming the file to just `.env`
- moving the file to the root of the project
- passing `{path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env')}`
- passing `{path: process.cwd() + '\\.env'}`
- loading dotenv from command line with the nodenv executable
- renaming properties to `REACT_APP_PORT` and such

Comment: The issue was resolved. The problem was wrong encoding of `.env` - it was encoded in utf16-LE, while dotenv parses utf8 by default. Once I resaved `.env` in utf8, it was successfully parsed.

Comment: Is dotenv a dependency in your package.json?

Comment: @Brewha Yes. Right now I managed to get it to work correctly, as described in the comment above.